# Google Ad mob ads showing invalid characters in place of ad on version 5.0.2

Tags: android, admob, android-5.0-lollipop

I am displaying Google Ad mob ads in my application. Its working fine on all devices up to 4.4.4 android version. But on Moto G(2nd version) with lollipop version 5.0.2, its displaying some special characters instead of ad. Can anyone help ?

Here is the screenshot from my app - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng3k63z4yacqnf4/MyCloud.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Could you be more specific - a screenshot would help us realise what the issue could be?

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh - here is the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/ng3k63z4yacqnf4/MyCloud.jpg?dl=0